# How to set default date in DatePickerField in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have a problem with sencha touch datepicker field. I want to set default (current date) in datepicker field but I am not able to find a way to do that. I am using sencha architect and there is no property exist to set default date in datepickerfield.

I am using the following code in **value** property of datepickerfield:

```
{
    year: (new Date()).getFullYear(), 
    day: 1, 
    month: 5
}
```

But application stop working when using above code to display date.

Please tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the 'value' property

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-cfg-value

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add an initialize function to whatever class contains your datepicker.

- Select that class.
- Then add an initialize function from the config
  panel.
- Then add the following code to the initialize function:

  ```
  var picker = this.down('datepicker');

  picker.setConfig({
      value: new Date()
  });

  this.callParent();
  ```

Of course if you have multiple datepickers you'll want to give it an item id and use `this.down('#thedatepicker');`

[image: inside architect]

Comment: you can also replace new Date() with { year: new Date().getFullYear, day: 1, month: 5 }

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the config of the container itself as follows:

```
 xtype: 'datepickerfield',
        value: new Date(),
        picker: {
            yearFrom: 2015,
            yearTo: 2030
        }
```